# jQuery get all checked value not working

Tags: jquery, html

Anyone can please help me why it returning an empty array. and thanks in advance. you can check code on http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Listing.

**Code sample :**

```js
function search(){
  var pettype = [];
  
  $(".pettype :checked").each(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
      pettype.push($(this).val());
  })
  
  alert(pettype);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="pettype" value="Lost" onclick="search();">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="pettype" value="Found" onclick="search();">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove the extra space in the following line :

```
$(".pettype :checked").each(function(){
___________^
```

Should be :

```
$(".pettype:checked").each(function(){
```

Else the selector will serch for checked elements inside `.pettype` elements.

Hope this helps.

```js
function search(){
  var pettype = [];
  $(".pettype:checked").each(function(){
      console.log($(this).val());
      pettype.push($(this).val());
  })
  alert(pettype);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="pettype" value="Lost" onclick="search();">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="pettype" value="Found" onclick="search();">
```

I suggest to attach the event in the JS code instead of inline attachement, like :

```js
$('.pettype').on('change', function(){
  var pettype = [];
  $(".pettype:checked").each(function(){
      pettype.push($(this).val());
  })
  console.log(pettype);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="pettype" value="Lost" />
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="pettype" value="Found" />
```

Answer (score -1):

actually i think you made a very tiny mistake... you had `$(".pettype :checked")` but it has to be `$(".pettype:checked")` because otherwise jQuery is searching for a checked element that is a child of pettype and not actually pettype :)

```js
function search(){
    var pettype = [];
    $(".pettype:checked").each(function(){
        pettype.push($(this).val());
    })
    alert(pettype);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML Code:

<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="pettype" value="Lost" onclick="search();">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" class="pettype" value="Found" onclick="search();">
```